# Spring MVC Thymeleaf : Error with code 400 returned with the message Bad Request

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf with Spring MVC for views and controllers, i've DataTable contain a returned results.

I've have also a form for filter the DataTable with fields

The code of my form and my DataTable is :

```
<form id="line_form" th:object="${lineFilter}" method="post" action="#">

<table id="line_table_result" class="table table-responsive"
dt:table="true" dt:theme="bootstrap2"           dt:url="@{/listFilteredByAccount}"
dt:serverside="true" dt:processing="true" dt:pageable="true"
dt:pagingType="full_numbers" dt:serverParam="getExtraParams"
dt:dom="lpirt" dt:autowidth="false" dt:displayLength="10"
dt:lengthMenu="'10,25,50,100,1000'"             dt:filterSelector="#filterButton">
```

In controller, i've this method :

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/listFilteredByAccount", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public DatatablesResponse<LineVO> getLineFilteredListWithAccount(@RequestParam(value="lineFilter") String lineFilterString, @DatatablesParams DatatablesCriterias criterias, Model model, Locale locale, HttpServletRequest req, String entity)
```

When i try to call this method, i've this error in my console :

Error with code 400 returned for /listFilteredByAccount with the message Bad Request

I'm trying to delete `@RequestParam(value="lineFilter")`, with this update, i can access method but the fileds of Object LineFilter are always null.

what i've forgot for resolve this ?

Thank's

Comment: What you want to do with this method? Is it a post or get? try `method="RequestMethod.GET" or POST` and you are missing the lineFilter Parameter while requesting the url. It should be something like `http://localhost:8080//listFilteredByAccount?lineFilter=SOME_VALUE` for GET request. If it is post you need to use `@ModelAttribute` instead of `@RequestParam`

Comment: It's a post method

Comment: Then you should use Model attribute to get the form data. i.e. line filter object